# How to add image url to Magento 2 Rest call “rest/V1/categories”?

Tags: php, rest, magento2

in magento 2.1:

Categories Rest api "rest/V1/categories" returns data as follows :

```
    {
  "id": 0,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "is_active": true,
  "position": 0,
  "level": 0,
  "product_count": 0,
  "children_data": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

how to modify it to include the **category image** ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the custom attributes you can use the `/V1/categories/{id}` API where you will find the image under the `custom_attributes` section.

If you need to have it in the list of categories instead:

You can find which method and module is called looking at the [webapi.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml#L340) and the [di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml#L24). Following the code from here you can see that the code leads you to [the category tree](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Tree.php#L90).

So you can create a plugin (interceptor) to add your field there.